# React native. listview can't scroll when it is inside a scrollview. (iOS work, but android not)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[React Native android] Any body know how to make listview scroll when it is embedded in a scrollview? It is work for iOS, but not work for android.

```
<ScrollView>
    <Text>test1</Text>
    <Text>test2<Text>
    <ListView/>
<scrollview>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the right way to go. Even if you manage to make this work, it's a bad practice. Remember that the main difference between a ScrollView and a ListView is that the ListView renders only the visible items and recycles them in order to optimize memory usage. By adding the ListView in a ScrollView you're likely to "sabotage" this feature.

Instead of trying to add the ListView in the ScrollView, use only a ListView with items of different type. Something along the lines:

```
export default class MyListComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
        this.state = {
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.data)
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ListView
                enableEmptySections={true}
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={(rowData) => this._getViewForType(rowData)}/>
        );
    }

    _getViewForType(rowData) {
        switch (rowData.renderType) {
            case 'type1':
                return <Text>test1</Text>
            case 'type2':
                return <Text>test2</Text>
            default:
                // Render your normal/default listview item here.
                return ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now before rendering this view, you just need add two extra items in your list of items: one of type "type1" and another one of type "type2".

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!

Comment: One more question, if in the scrollview, we have some InputText and one button, when I click button I want to pop up&close the listview(height is 200, and is scrollable). How can I do?

Comment: You would have to change the state of the component by using `setState()`. This triggers another call to the component's `render()` function. Then in the `render()` you can check the state and based on it you can show/hide the child components.

Comment: what I want is in the scrollview, there are some InputText and one button, when I click button show a listview(height:200) below the button. But now the listview can't scroll. (The reason why I make the rootview as scrollview is the keyboard will hide content if InputText is focused. )  Any ideas about this, use only a ListView with items of different type seems not work(my item type is another listview).